# how to get window location after window.open

Tags: javascript

All I want to get address bar URL, tried with this javascript, but shows as location{} (empty value)

```
var googleWindow = window.open('https://api.something/givetokenafterclosed');

var waitForToken = setInterval(function () {
    console.log(googleWindow.location)
    if (googleWindow.closed) {
        clearInterval(waitForToken);
    }
    if (window.location.hash) {
        // here I'm retrieving some token...
        googleWindow.close();
    }
}, 3000); // time interval set to 3 secs
```

If I open localhost urls It works fine. Help me to get opened window URL in above case.

Comment: I believe you can only access the window if it's in the same domain, same for using window.opener from the child window.

Comment: did you check if you are getting any javascript errors? the scenario u saying outside of `domain`.. can cause `access denined exception` in js... for example `www.abc.com/test` opening `www.abc.com\test1` will work... but `www.abc.com/test` opening `www.pqr.com\test1` will not work

Comment: yeah.. My case is in different domains. Thus it doesn't allow.

Answer (score 3):

The URL, when the window has loaded a document on another origin, may contain confidential information and so the browser will not give your JS access to it.

If you want to get a token from another domain, then the other domain needs to redirect back to your domain and pass the token.